# make request from frontend to backend having multiple node js server in minikube

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nginx, kubernetes

i am new to kubernetes(minikube). I have an application with frotnend(vue cli) and backend(python, node js). On the frontend i am using nginx to serve the vue build version. My nginx config is like this.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;
  server {
    listen       80;
    location / {
      root   /frontend;
      index  index.html;
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
      root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
  }
}
```

in my vue.config.js i have configuration that is redirecting to the backend which having 4 node js server listening to ports 3001,3002,3003,3004.
My vue.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: "/",
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      "^/api/server/v1": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000",
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: { "^/api/server/v1": "/api/server" },
      },
      "^/mongo-api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5001",
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/mongo-api": "",
        },
      },
      "^/mongo-stream": {
        target: "http://localhost:3004",
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/mongo-stream": "",
        },
      },
      "^/rest-api": {
        target: "http://localhost:5002",
        logLevel: "debug",
        changeOrigin: true,
        pathRewrite: {
          "^/rest-api": "",
        },
      },
      "^/api": {
        target: "https://api.binance.com",
        logLevel: "debug",
      },
    },
  },
}
```

Now my question is that how can i make request to the backend from frontend. I have already configured the deployment and services for this and it is using Clusterip on the backend pods and nodeip on the frontend service.
i was using localhost for all my communication in case of running with docer-compose.yaml.
My backend-server-service.yaml is like this

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kompose.cmd: kompose convert --build=local -v
    kompose.service.type: clusterip
    kompose.version: 1.21.0 (992df58d8)
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: backend-server
  name: backend-server
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "3000"
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  - name: "3001"
    port: 3001
    targetPort: 3001
  - name: "3002"
    port: 3002
    targetPort: 3002
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: backend-server
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I am using Kompose command to generate deployments and services.**Now how can i configure the nginx like when i make request to localht:3000 or localhost:3001 then it will redirect to my container inside pod and which is inside a cluster**

Answer (score 2):

If both the frontend and the backend are running in the same namespace, it should be as simple as replacing `http://localhost:3000` with `http://backend-server:3000`, where `backend-server` is the name of the backend server `Service`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. previously i was using devServer.proxy in vue.config file, now i am using nginx to handle all these requests. I have commented devServer section in vue.config file. Now it is working locally using docker-compose up and making request to localhost:3000 or localhost:30001/api-server some thing like this.

Comment: Now i am using minikube to do this work on kubernetes. So now my server_name in nginx will be node_ip:node_port which is http://172.17.0.2:30001/ like this. So my get request or websoket request should be some thing like this http://172.17.0.2:30001/api-server. And websocket request is http://172.17.0.2:30001:3002. Can you currect me so that i can use the service name.